# Cannot Redirect to a page in React Redux with Sagas

Tags: reactjs, web, redux, react-router, redux-saga

**When I want to redirect** to the '/welcome' page at the end of the 'submit()' function nothing happens. This is the submit function:

```
function submit ({ firstName, lastName, email }, submitAction) {

    let error = {}
    let isError = false

    if(firstName.trim() === '') {
        error.firstName = 'Required'
        isError = true
    }

    if(isError) {
        throw new SubmissionError(error)
    } else {
        //submit form to local storage
        console.log('before calling submit')
        submitAction({firstName, lastName, email})
        //Redirect to another page  
        return <Redirect to="/welcome"/>    
    }
}
```

If you need some other info about my project, feel free to leave a comment!
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `withRouter` HoC from React Router to provide `{ match, history, location }` to your component as follows;

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

...

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginPage));
```

With `history` you can do a `history.push("/welcome")` when async function will resolve

Comment: Did that, but now it says that "submitAction is not a function" . The weird thing is that before doing this, the function was executed normally.

Comment: did you pass `history` to function arguments? Maybe you changed the order of arguments and now `submitAction` is at wrong place?

Comment: Should I pass history to the submit function? The edit that I did was importing withRouter and exporting as you told me to do :0

Comment: wait, is sumbit function belongs to you Component and you want to run saga action by `submitAction`? I assumed you have you logic inside saga. In that case you don't have to pass `history` as it's a property of connected Component, but you can't just submitAction just like that. If you are using Redux, you have to dispatch actions